# R - Make list element into a header

Tags: r, list, structure, element

It happened that two elements within the list given over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46502973/6210219) did not conform to the pattern. What this means is, after applying @akrun's code to that list, I am left with the following problem:

```
lst <- list(A = c('aa','bb','B', 'cc', 'dd', 'C', 'ee', 'ff'), D = (c('aa', 'bb')))

$A
 [1] "aa" "bb" "B" "cc" "dd" "C"  "ee" "ff"

$D
[1] "aa" "bb"
```

Without affecting the overall list structure, how do I make "B" and "C" headers of their respective elements so that:

```
lst2 <- list(A=c('aa', 'bb'), B=c('cc', 'dd'), C=c('ee', 'ff'), D=c('aa', 'bb'))

$A
[1] "aa" "bb"

$B
[1] "cc" "dd"

$C
[1] "ee" "ff"

$D
[1] "aa" "bb"
```

---

I managed to work out a solution to the actual problem like this:

```
> lst <- list('隱公元年', c("", 'aa'), 'bb', 'cc', '莊公十年', 'aa', 'bb', '襄公二十四年', c("", 'dd'), '成公三年', 'ee')

> v1 <- unlist(lst)
> v2 <- lapply(v1, function(x){x[!x ==""]}) %>% compact %>% unlist() #Remove empty string

> i1 <- cumsum(grepl(".公+[元一二三四五六七八九十]+年$", v2)) #Generate index based on Regex of intended headers. 

> zz <- tapply(v2, i1, FUN = function(x) x[-1]) #Apply index to dataset, ignoring first element (which is the header). 
> names(zz) <- tapply(v2, i1, FUN = head, 1) #Apply headers to dataset. 

> zz
$隱公元年
[1] "aa" "bb" "cc"

$莊公十年
[1] "aa" "bb"

$襄公二十四年
[1] "dd"

$成公三年
[1] "ee"
```

Comment: Could you please check your example and expected output as the expected output seems to be for a different input data

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out the error. I decided to change the input data last minute and forgot to update the output. Just edited the output to accurately reflect the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option where we `stack` the `list` to a 2 column 'data.frame' ('d1').  Convert that to `data.table` (`setDT(d1)`), specify the `i` with logical condition i.e. check for upper case elements in 'values' and assign (`:=`) those values to 'ind' column on that position.  Based on a grouping variable created with the  position of `unique` elements in 'ind' compared with sequence of rows, get the cumulative sum, use this to assign the 'ind' as the first element of 'ind' (`ind[1]`), keep the rows where the 'values' are not equal to 'ind' and `split` the 'values' by the 'ind' column

```
d1 <- stack(lst)
library(data.table)
d2 <- setDT(d1)[grepl("[A-Z]", values), ind := values][, 
  ind := ind[1L] , cumsum(seq_len(nrow(d1)) %in% match(unique(ind), ind))][values != ind]
split(d2$values, d2$ind)
#$A
#[1] "aa" "bb" "cc"

#$D
#[1] "aa" "bb"

#$B
#[1] "aa" "bb" "cc" "dd"

#$C
#[1] "ee" "ff"
```

---

Or we can try with `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
fsplitLst <- function(lstt){

f1 <- function(x) {
     i1 <- grepl("[A-Z]", x)
     grp <- cumsum(i1)
     split(x[!i1], grp[!i1])
     
   }
 map(lstt, f1) %>%
        flatten %>%
        set_names(., map2(names(lstt), lstt, ~grep("[A-Z]", c(.x, .y), value = TRUE)) %>%
           unlist)
 }
fsplitLst(lst)
#$A
#[1] "aa" "bb" "cc"

#$B
#[1] "aa" "bb" "cc" "dd"

#$C
#[1] "ee" "ff"

#$D
#[1] "aa" "bb"
```

#### data

```
lst <- list(A = c('aa','bb','cc', 'B', 'aa','bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'C', 'ee', 'ff'),
             D = c('aa', 'bb'))
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Why does $D get listed before $B and $C in the first example?

Comment: I got the following error when applying the tidyverse solution to the actual data: 　　　　　　　　　　　　　
Called from: abort("`nm` must be `NULL` or a character vector the same length as `x`")
　　　　　　　　　　　　　
function (msg, type = NULL, call = FALSE) 
{
  cnd <- cnd_error(type, .msg = msg, .call = sys.call(-1))
  if (call) {
    cnd$call <- cnd$.call
  }
  stop(cnd)
}

Comment: I think I know the reason for the error. In the actual data, the headers all have a regular pattern as such: " X公X年 " 〔"隱公元年", "莊公十二年", "襄公二十四年" etc.〕. The regular expression used to identify the headers in the given example, "[A-Z]", is used to separate A, B, C, D from the rest of the elements. So my next question will be: can grepl() and grep() be fed a regular expression so that it can accurately capture my intended headers?